# How can I remove specific lines block wise using linux commands?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have following data file, made up of repeating data blocks.

```
 486  Examples                    Iteration:  300000 #Bonds:  10
    1    6    3    5    7  371    0    0    0    0    0    0    1  0.935  0.932  0.955  0.852  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  3.736  0.000  1.303
    2    6    4  143  386  389    0    0    0    0    0    0    1  0.892  0.877  0.855  0.918  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  3.751  0.000  0.999
    3    3    1   18    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1  0.935  0.901  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.926  2.000 -0.708
    4    3    2   18    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1  0.892  0.923  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.829  2.000 -0.756
...
  482    3   16  483    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1  0.954  0.831  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.809  2.000 -0.716
  483    2  482    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1  0.831  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.884  0.000  0.457
  484    2  485    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  105  0.865  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.936  0.000  0.372
  485    3  213  484    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  105  0.835  0.865  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.779  2.000 -0.665
  486    2  440    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   44  0.829  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.896  0.000  0.345
   634.597636118845        347.992894465888        1330.58342505062
 -1.280885974547230E-005
 486  Examples                    Iteration:  300001 #Bonds:  10
    1    6    3    5    7  371    0    0    0    0    0    0    1  0.935  0.932  0.955  0.852  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  3.736  0.000  1.303
    2    6    4  143  386  389    0    0    0    0    0    0    1  0.892  0.877  0.855 
...
```

Like wise, my data file is made up of lots of data blocks, and each data blocks have total 489 lines each. But the real data lines are only 486 lines, and there are 1 header line and 2 tailing lines.

Here, I hope to remove 1 header line and 2 tailing lines for all data blocks, (remove every (1 * n, 488 * n, and 489 * n )-th lines for all data. n = number of datablocks) and remove all columns of floats (read until 13th column only). So, I hope to get the file like

```
    1    6    3    5    7  371    0    0    0    0    0    0    1  
    2    6    4  143  386  389    0    0    0    0    0    0    1  
    3    3    1   18    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
    ...
    484    2  485    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  105
    485    3  213  484    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  105
    486    2  440    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   44
    1    6    3    5    7  371    0    0    0    0    0    0    1  
    2    6    4  143  386  389    0    0    0    0    0    0    1 
    ...
```

this format. How can I remove 1 header line + 2 tailing lines every data block? I think I could do read first 13 columns by awk print command. But I have no idea how to remove those extra lines from data. Are there easy way of doing this with awk + NR combo or other linux commands?

Thanks

Comment: Is there uniquely identifiable information on the header and tail lines? Is the number of fields useful for that?

Comment: @EtanReisner Some numbers of header and tailing lines are useful in the future analysis, but I have fortran 90 code to do that. For now, I'm interested in just remove headers and tailing lines, and remove 14~last columns.

Comment: What have you tried?  I'd love to help you with your awk script, but you'll need to post the code in order for us to help you improve it.

Comment: Would it be valid to say you only want to keep the lines that have 16 fields? If so, then `awk 'NF == 16 { $14=""; $15=""; $16=""; print}' file.dat` would probably be sufficient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out the non-data lines in every block by using a modulus to only print specific lines. You can then print only the first 13 colums using a for loop.

```
awk 'NR  % 489 != 0 && NR % 489 != 1 && NR % 489 != 488 {for (i = 1; i < 13; i++) printf "%s\t",$i; print ""}' Input.txt
```

Some explanation:

NR is the row number, which starts at 1. `&&` is the logical `AND`. We are printing all rows whose number `mod 489` does not match 1, 488 and 489.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but entire column repeats after 13th column. How can I escape from that?

Comment: Also, could you explain how NR and && commands works in here?

Comment: @exsonic01 I assume you meant the entire row repeats. I made an edit which should fix that.

Comment: Thank you. Please check my understanding is correct about your code. 'NR % 489' means for all repeating 489 lines, and '!=0' means read except last tailing line, and '!=1' means read except last-1 tailing line, and '!=488' means header line. Is this right?

Comment: @exsonic01, `!=1` refers to the header line, `!=0` refers to 489 and `!=488` refers to the second to last line.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the sample lines are truly representative of the data then something like this might work.

```
awk 'NF <= 8 {next} NF=13' datafile
```

That will lose the column formatting though. Under the assumption that every line has a value in every column you could reconstruct a columnar format by piping that output to `column -t` though that wouldn't be identical to the input.

The `8` in that snippet was an arbitrary number larger than the number of fields on any of the example lines given and smaller than `13`.

Comment: Thanks. Format is not that important here, but I prefer %7d. I could use awk printf to make the columns again in format. BTW, could you explain that awk commands? Also how can I remove 1 header and 2 tailing lines ?

Comment: You can certainly manually format the output instead of letting awk print it by default there. Just use a `{for (i=1; i<=13; i++) {printf "%7d%s", $i, OFS}}` or something like that.

Comment: That script drops those lines in the first `{next}` block because they have fewer than `8` fields. (Eight was an arbitrary number larger than the example lines given and smaller than 13.)